# How to show and count how many same characters in 2 arrays

Tags: c#, string

The Code goes like this:

```
        string a = txtInput.Text.ToLower();
        string b = txtInput2.Text.ToLower();

        char[] arraya = a.ToCharArray();
        char[] arrayb = b.ToCharArray();

        var ar = arrayb.Where(arraya.Contains);

        //bool equals = ;
        foreach (char i in ar)
        {
            txtAnalisa.Text = i + "\n";
        }
```

But txtAnalisa only prints 1 characters. I want to show all same values (that belongs to  arrayb and arraya.

Example =

if a values qweq, and
if b values qweqwea,

the txtAnalisa results is 'qweq'. Also i want to count how many same characters from those 2 arrays. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txtAnalisa.Text = i + "\n";
```

You're overwriting the value of `txtAnalisa.Text` here with every iteration of the loop. You probably want something like this:

```
txtAnalisa.Text += i + "\n";
```

You can count the length of an array with the `.Count()` extension method.

Comment: On the collection you wish to count the number of items, so something like `ar.Count()`. It's a LINQ extension method, so you'll need to make sure `using System.Linq;` is at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to use `foreach` loop. You can try **[`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**:

```
 txtAnalisa.Text = String.Join("\n", a.Where(x => b.Contains(x)));
```

If you want to get the count of distinct characters which are included in the second array, then you can use `Distinct().Count()` or just `Count()` if you don't want:

```
 var resultCount = a.Distinct().Count(x => b.Contains(x));
```